# I have two Google accounts, how to verify they are NOT LINKED

Tags: google-account

I opened a second Google account so I could make a business page years ago.  The owner did not believe in social media.  But I had a vision and did it.   I no longer work there. They want the passwords to that account.

I would like to delete it all together so there is no tie with the former company. IF it's not linked to any of MY personal Google stuff. I really don't care if they use it or not. Unless there are reasons to not give it to the company I used to work for.

How do I know it is NOT linked to my Google account I use every day, my Google Calendar, emails, documents, pictures etc.?

Answer (score 0):

The only ways it could possibly be "linked" to your other account is if you used the email address for one as the recovery email address for the other, or if you set up mail forwarding to have messages from one sent to the other. If you haven't done that there's nothing to worry about.

In any event, you can see what is in each account at [Google: My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).